# Does anyone used css units in, cm, mm, pc, ex? In what context?

Tags: css

I used css units, px and em frequently & seldom pt.
But wonder, on what context other units in, cm, mm, pc, ex are used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These units are used for media other than screen, such as printing etc.

I haven't yet began using it for such purposes but will very soon.

Answer (score 1):

My HTML resume uses them in [@media print](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css_mediatypes.asp) clauses.

Answer (score 1):

See [this article](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/css/units.html) on CSS Units.

**Excerpt:**

> Absolute length units are highly
>   dependent on the output medium, and so
>   are less useful than relative units.
>   The following absolute units are
>   available:
>
> - in (inches; 1in=2.54cm)
> - cm (centimeters; 1cm=10mm)
> - mm (millimeters)
> - pt (points; 1pt=1/72in)
> - pc (picas; 1pc=12pt)

So -- **absolute units** are useful for specific output medium, but not much else. **Relative units** are the better choice (and hence much more commonly used) since they adjust better depending on the output medium.